# Fantasy book where a dimensional creature absorbs a dragon and a unicorn

Tags: story-identification, books

Honestly, when I was reading this book I always felt like I was starting after book one and it was confusing. But it's always been on my mind, so I want to figure it out and clear up the confusion and re-read it.

I remember the main character is a girl. But there is a side male character and he was supposed to be the main character's brother. But for some reason, things got changed and he wasn't. I don't remember a whole lot about this book, although I know at the end some kind of dimensional creature absorbs a dragon and a unicorn. And then the side character takes the girl and some other people to another dimension until it is safe.

Comment: Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy! This question would be improved by going through the checklists here; [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question)

Comment: Could you please elaborate on *I always felt like I was starting after book one it was confusing*? The wording is kind of confusing and I can't really understand what you're trying to say :)

Comment: @NikitaNeganov up to Justin to confirm, but the way I read it, they felt like it was the second book of a series, and not having read the first, they got really confused about what was going on

Comment: Ya that about sums it up.